# Copying Folder Contents with Subdirectories Over FTP

Tags: ftp

I have a folder that contains multiple subdirectories. I would like to copy the contents of the folder over ftp (using lftp preferably) instead of the entire folder.

When I use the mirror command, it seems to copy the folder over, which means that my files are one level higher than expected.

Comment: Can you show an example of the directory structures on both sides (local and remote)?

Comment: No problem.
Local side: public, which contains folder1, folder2, folder3, multiple files
Server side: I have a folder www.
My goal is to copy folder1, folder2, folder3 and the multiple files inside public directly to www.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use this form of the command to download:

```
% lftp -e 'mirror <remote download dir> <local download dir>' -u <username>,<pass> -p <port> <hostname>
```

If you want the contents of the folder just add the trailing slash like so:

```
% lftp -e 'mirror /some/remote/directories/contents/ /my/home/downloads/somedir/.' -u joeuser ftp.remotesys.com
```